# Why does using os.environ in settings cause Django not to run?

Tags: python, django

I'm running Django 1.5.1. In my settings.py file, I have:

```py
import os, dj_database_url

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL']),
    'mongodb': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['MONGO_URL']),
}
```

And I have a local settings file with:

```py
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'mysql://root@localhost/my-database'
```

When I try to run `python manage.py runserver --settings=foo.local_settings`, it throws `Unknown command: 'runserver'`. If I take out the os.environ parts, though, it works.

I can't figure what's going on; does anyone have any ideas? Also, if there is a better way to approach what I'm doing - that is, offload the environment settings to local values - please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `import os` in local settings file?

Comment: What's in your 'manage.py'? They changed significantly at some django version.

Comment: Try run `python local_settings.py` and see if you have any error.

Comment: @Guandalino - that put me on the right path. Basically I had local_settings.py doing `from settings import *`, which in turn was throwing an error that `os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` was not yet set. I moved the import line under the rest of the stuff in local_settings.py, and now it works. (Well, it brought up other errors, but it solved this one.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to Guandalino. Basically I had local_settings.py doing `from settings import *`, which in turn was throwing an error that `os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` was not yet set. I moved the import line under the rest of the stuff in local_settings.py, and now it works.